# D365 FO Publish custom created workspace

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365

I created entire new workspace in D365 FO. Entire workspace with tiles, tabbed lists, links is done. I see it when I debug with that workspace like starting object.

Now, I need to publish it to rest of users. How to publish that workspace on mine environment ? Is there some tutorial or document how to do that, I can't find it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have followed the guide provided by Microsoft found [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/dev-itpro/user-interface/build-workspace) and thus you have already done the following:

1. Created the form for the workspace with a form pattern of Operational Workspace.
2. Created the menu item for the form that links to the form.
3. Created security privileges/duties/roles that can be added to users that are NOT sys admin

If the above steps are done, I assume by publish you mean: **1.** Add it to either the landing page that contains all the tile links to the different workspaces and/or **2.** Adding it to a modules's workspace submenu.

**Answer part 1** 
To add it to the general workspace tile landing page, create a tile for the menu item. Refer to an example tile such as AssetWorkspace in AOT > User Interface > Tiles > AssetWorkspace. Once you have created a tile correctly (see the documentation in link above if more help required for this) you can add it via extension to the navpanemenu

[image]

**Answer part 2**
Adding the tile to a workspace navigation submenu is as simple as dragging and dropping the tile you created in answer part 1 onto the appropriate submenu (example here is of the Accounts payable module:

[image]